# HAL clients or examples of accessing HAL API

Tags: admin-on-rest

Question: Any HAL clients or examples of accessing HAL API with admin-on-rest ?

I got started because HAL was mentioned in the first paragraph of the introduction, but now I'm having trouble finding any examples or anyone else using HAL rest client, so I am winding up for now just writing a bunch of simple findAll repositories on top of the already robust existing HAL API.

Comment: All community REST clients are already documented. Writing your own is pretty simple. I think the HAL reference was only a reference. If you do end up writing your own client then do consider open sourcing it.

Comment: Maybe I can be more specific, but the part that I'm not sure about is that in HAL it works with links to your entities, instead of putting them in the json response itself.  E.g. If there's a Post with a User in it, the User won't be in the content part of the json, it will actually be in the separate links section as a link to the URL for the users for that Post. Is this a GET_MANY_REFERENCE?  I'm not sure where this fits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a more concise answer here that isn't polluted with my thought process now that I've got it all figured out (for anyone's future reference)... Again assuming the HAL API was made with Spring Data Rest.

The four major keys to this integration are:

1. Exposing foreign key attributes in your JPA entities, which is required in several places by admin-on-rest `@Column(name="parentEntity", updatable=false, insertable=false) private Integer parentEntityId;`
2. Exposing all your entity IDs using `RepositoryRestConfiguration.exposeIdsFor( MyEntity.class )`
3. Annotate your repositories as `@RepositoryRestResource` and have them extend `PagingAndSortingRepository<MyEntity, Integer>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<MyEntity>` to expose extremely useful search filters by attribute name (e.g. `/api/myEntitys?field1=foo&field2=bar`).
4. When submitting create and save requests with foreign keys make sure to adjust your `params.data` to include the linked resource (e.g. 'http://myserver.com/api/myEntitys/19') on top of (or in place of, HAL has no use for it) the foreign key you exposed in 1. (e.g. myEntityId=19)

Other small items of note:

use PATCH instead of PUT when updating (you may be able to use PUT if you are more of a hibernate expert and can map your entities better than I can but I had trouble getting it mapped perfectly and HAL's PATCH will take partial entities)

When submitting GET_LIST and GET_MANY_REFERENCE you get the total number of items and pagination parameters from the 'page' section of the response, and you use 'size' and 'page' query params in your API requests. (so, no need for headers and stuff)

To change the default 'equals' filter for any string entries (from 3. above) to a 'contains' filter, you will have to also extend `QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QMyEntity>` and provide your own customize method in each of your repositories. For example:

`default void customize( QuerydslBindings bindings, QChampion champion )
    {
        bindings.bind( String.class ).first( ( StringPath path, String value ) -> path.contains( value ) );
    }`

Answer (score 1):

We don't have any examples for HAL specifically. However, the point of this introduction was that admin-on-rest is backend agnostic.

You can create your own custom rest client by following the [documentation](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/RestClients.html#writing-your-own-rest-client). Read the code of existing ones for inspiration.

Comment: Maybe I can be more specific, but the part that I'm not sure about is that in HAL it works with links to your entities, instead of putting them in the json response itself. E.g. If there's a Post with a User in it, the User won't be in the content part of the json, it will actually be in the separate links section as a link to the URL for the users for that Post. Is this a GET_MANY_REFERENCE? I'm not sure where this fits. Seems like it's almost like a "GET_ONE_REFERENCE" or something but that's not a thing.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone referencing this in the future, if you happen to be in control of your API through Spring Data Rest you can consider the use of an excerptProjection on every one of your existing repositories that shows an inline version of your entity. This would work if there were absolutely nothing besides admin-on-rest accessing your API.

For my case I am planning on writing a custom projection for every rest resource that has entities and naming it the same thing: "inline". Then in the admin-on-rest restClient, just always asking for the inline projection on every GET_MANY or GET_MANY_REFERENCE request.

This is the best I have at the moment. It's not perfect but for the amount of entities I have it's still many weeks faster than building a CRUD interface from scratch so I highly recommend admin-on-rest.

Comment: I was doing the above with some success but in the end I just decided to conform to what admin-on-rest wants in many cases which is an exposed foreign key.   E.g. on the child entity do this     @Column(name="parentEntity", updatable=false, insertable=false)
    private Integer parentEntityId;

Comment: Further, don't use "@JsonManagedReference" in your child entity class, as you won't get a Parent object sent in and Spring Data will not know how to create an entity. Not sure what the consequences are tbh but it's working. You still have to use "@JsonBackReference" in the parent entity when referencing the child.

Comment: (will post more tomorrow when I figure out how to get the restClient to use HAL's /api/entity/search which is different from /api/entitys)

Comment: Oh and the reason I chose to expose the foreign key instead is because you need to expose that foreign key anyway in the Create and Edit views, and it's going to hit the API again anyway in a Reference field/input so you might as well not embed the entities